# Problems with background Worker and Data Table

Tags: c#

Hi all I have a BAckground worker and a Datatable. I have a timer also . I am filling the data table in timer and In Backgroundworker_Progress changed I am assigining it to my DataGrid as my DataSource. But even after the process has been completed  . My Background worker is not getting Completed .Due to which my application crashes.This happens only when I launch my exe directly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with @Simon. Paste some code so that we understand what might be wrong.
Also, why are you using timer for?

Don't assign the `DataTable` in `ProgressChanged` event. Do it in `RunWorkerCompleted` event. Here is what I think you should do:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        e.Result = GetTableData();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        e.Result = ex;
    }
}

private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // only display progress, do not assign it to grid
}

private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Result is DataTable)
    {
       dataGridView1.DataSource = e.Result as DataTable;
    }
    else if (e.Result is Exception)
    {
    }
}

private DataTable GetTableData()
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    for (int i = 0; i < NumOfRows; i++)
    {
        //... fill data here
        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(i * 100F / NumOfRows);
    }
    return table;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access GUI controls from a background thread without doing an invoke().

I suspect this is your problem, if not you may need to provide some code of the part that is causing the problem.

For more information see:

- [MSDN - InvokeRequired](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired.aspx)
- [MSDN - Invoke(...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b.aspx)]
- [StackOverflow question - How to update GUI from another thread in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661561/how-to-update-gui-from-another-thread-in-c)

If you wrap the code in your background worker in a Try/Catch block, or change your visual studio settings to display all exceptions you will see an exception that explains what is going wrong.